# Create Symlink Glob of directory read from a file

Tags: awk, symlink, wildcards, csv

I am extracting names of directory at 5th column of tsv file `ExtensionList.tsv` and I want to create symlinks to all those folders with names beginning with that located at ${HOME} inside Extension folder

```bsh
awk -F'\t' '{print $5 }' ExtensionList.tsv \
    | xargs -L 1 -I "{}" ln -s -f "${HOME}/{}"* Extension
```

---

Sample Tsv file

```
2   n   xshrim.txt-syntax   Txt Syntax  xshrim.txt-syntax
```

I want to do (for all records in tsv file)

```bsh
ln -s -f xshrim.txt-syntax* Extension
```

#### Any suggestions?

#### Why did my command didn't work?

Comment: You need `awk '{print $6}'` since the name you want is in column 6.

Comment: @HatLess It is tab separated file! there are only 5 columns

Comment: Yes. Now it is 5 columns. When I responded, it was 6 columns. You have since added the `-` to `Txt Syntax` which was space seperated. `awk` uses space or tab delimiters by default. Removing the `-F"\t"` from your code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glob expansion must be done for each name read from the TSV file separately.  This can be done by calling `sh -c` from `xargs` once for each directory name.

```bash
cut -f 5 ExtensionList.tsv | 
  xargs -I {} sh -c 'ln -s -f "$HOME/$1"* Extension/' sh {}
```

Note that it assumes file names in that fifth column don't start with blanks and don't contain backslash, single quote nor double quote characters. With the GNU implementation of `xargs`, adding `-d '\n'` works around  those issues.

To avoid running one `sh` per file:

```bash
cut -f 5 ExtensionList.tsv | 
  xargs sh -c '
    ret=0
    for dirpath do
      ln -s -f "$HOME/$dirpath"* Extension/ || ret=$?
    done
    exit "$ret"' sh
```

On top of the limitations above, file paths must also not contain blanks anywhere. That extra limitation is also avoided with GNU `xargs`'  `-d '\n'`.

---

Refer: [is there a way to create symbolic link with wildcard - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121111/is-there-a-way-to-create-symbolic-link-with-wildcard)

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
typeset -U prefixes=( ${(f)"$(cut -f5 < ExtensionList.tsv)"} )
typeset -U regular_files_with_those_prefixes=( ~/$^prefixes*(N.) )
if (( $#regular_files_with_those_prefixes )); then
  ln -sf -- $regular_files_with_those_prefixes Extensions
fi
```

Where:

- `typeset -U`: makes sure the array elements are unique (are deduplicated)
- `${(f)"$(cmd)"}`: splits the output of `cmd` on line `f`eeds.
- `x/$^array` when `array=(a b c)` expands to `x/a` `x/b` `x/c` instead of `x/a` `b` `c` for `x/$array`.
- `(N.)`: glob qualifiers: `N` for `N`ullglob for globs to expand to nothing when there's no match. `.` to restrict the glob expansion to *regular* files to the exclusion of any other type of files (fifos, directories, symlinks...).